# Open a link in new tab, open another link and reload on that tab

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm not sure if there's a proper term for this behavior.

User story (there are 2 tabs):
1. User clicks first link on `Tab1`, a new tab (`Tab2`) opens up
2. User clicks second link on `Tab1`, `Tab2` refreshes to reflect second link clicked by user on `Tab1`.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: I really don't understand that can you show us any html. What framework are you using, what is the real use case. Can we have more detail?

Comment: jQuery tag is not required here, removed tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the first link in a new tab using a handle:

```
var tab = window.open('http://yoursite.com/action', '_blank');
```

and then simply change the location of the opened window when the user clicks the second link:

```
tab.location.href = 'http://yoursite.com/second-action';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @Hafiz's answer

You can open a *"named tab"* in Javascript using `window.open()` call.

For example:

```
/* The code I am writing is extremely stupid and should never be used professionally, it's just here to convey the point */
/* you html element. */
<a href="#" onlick="openLink('google.com','tab2', true)">1st Link</a>
<a href="#" onlick="openLink('google.de','tab2', false)">2nd Link</a>

/* openLink */
function openLink(url, tabName, focus) {
   var tab = window.open(url, tabName);
   if(focus)
      /* additionally if you want to focus on the tab, this might not work on some platform. Safari(may be on iOS) I think. */
      tab.focus(); 
}
```

You can read up on [open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and [focus()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp).